# Custom User management in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm having a PHP site with registered users. Now I'm going to create a WordPress site in a subdomain. Now, I want to use my existing user data on the new WordPress site.

Simply,

www.example.com is my site. It has some registered users. Which is built in PHP and I maintain the user data on my table. Now I would like to create wp.example.com with WordPress (Buddy Press exactly). Now I want my existing users to log in and use this WordPress site. Are there any possibilities?

Comment: Are both on the same server?

Comment: Yes, Both the sites are on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both services with each other by adding new actions to the wordpress login process. To do that the following steps need to be done:

1. Overwrite the login process by adding an action to wp_login with a priority of at least 11 but beneath 30:

   ```
   add_action('wp_login', 'yourLoginFunction', 11);
   ```
2. Create a REST API, or any other form of API, from which your wordpress Server can ask for user credentials on your other server:

   ```
   function yourLoginFunction($username, $user) {
       if (!is_empty($user)) {
           return $user; // User is already logged in.
       }
       $password = $_POST['password'];
       // call API on other server. Provide the given userdata from POST
       $userResult = callYourApi($username, $password);
       if ($userResult !== null) {
           $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
           if ($user === false) {
               //create new user
           }
           return $user;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Like this your user can use the account of your first page and login to your wordpress page aswell. Keep in mind that another user will be created for him on the wordpress site, so a password change or anything like that will not work, unless you program a sync for it.